# Django - How to calculate age of 10 years above

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Model with the normal:

```
date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Please help me calculate those that are 10 years and above and display them in html. I need to set it so that as soon as someone turns 10 on todays date it automatically displays them.

Comment: @LinhNguyen any idea?

Comment: Do you want a queryset or would like to do the logic in the model itself like making @property decorator or any custom method?

Comment: As long as I can call it in views.py and displayed in html. Please

Comment: Does the below solution works?

Comment: Can you share your exact model and view?

Comment: I am sorry but they are in my native lang. Please just elaborate on what goes to model.py if any and to views.py and how do I call it in html. Appreciate your great effort in helping solve this.

Comment: @ElikiBula is there any missing info in my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Use `relativedelta` to subtract 10 years from your current time, then use it in your queryset:

```
from django.utils import timezone 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

ten_years_ago_time = timezone.now() - relativedelta(years=10)
result = YourModel.objects.filter(date_of_birth__lt=ten_years_ago_time)
```

This code should goes to `views.py`, and nothing to do with `models.py`